# Spring boot: query on dbRef array

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I need to check if an string is contained into an array document field.

`Application` class is like:

```
@Document
public class Application {

   @Id
   private String code;

   @DBRef
   private List<ApplicationScope> scopes;
}
```

It can look like:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("...."),
  scopes: ["a", "b", "c"]
}
```

I need to find all documents where `scopes` field contains a given string.

I'm using `mongoTemplate` in order to implement this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add ApplicationScope class code

Comment: you can use $In (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) of mongodb to find that
e.g db.application.find({scopes:{$in:[ARRAY] }})
In mongotemplate 
mongoTemplate.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("scopes").in(ARRAY)),Application.class)